# Django UnicodeEncodeError when importing from db

Tags: python, django

I have a custom management command to import data from one db and create model instances from it. Basically it is:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, **kwargs):
        cursor = connections['db2'].cursor()
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM table'
        cursor.execute(sql)
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            my_model = MyModel(*row)
            my_model.save()
```

First I was importing from sqlite to sqlite and all went well. But when I switched to MySQL as my main db, I started getting UnicodeEncodeError, when calling `my_model.save()`. The caveat is that I have non-ascii symbols in db (namely Russian), but as I get, Django converts all strings to unicode. And yes, both dbs use utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that bug is due to mezzanine app, I'm using
https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1132